# PGFGantt Multiple Canvas Color

Tags: pgfgantt

I want to ask if it is possible in PGFGantt, to have a different canvas color from range lets say 0 to 4 and other color for range 5 to 8, when I am using

```
\gantttitlelist{0,...,8}{1}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [pgfgantt manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf) page 11, something like

```
\gantttitlelist[title/.style={fill=red}]{1,...,4}{1} 
\gantttitlelist[title/.style={fill=green}]{5,...,8}{1} \
```

is what you need.

[image]